# Identifying iframe-unfriendly sites in rails — even when x-frame-options is missing from header

Tags: iframe, x-frame-options

**Background:**

I'm working on a rails app that will open up articles inside the app itself via an iframe (with a navbar at the top from my app, kind of like StumbleUpon). But I've noticed some websites that publish articles (examples: pitchfork.com, vox.com, theverge.com) prevent themselves from being loaded in an iframe by setting X-Frame-Options to SAMEORIGIN or DENY.

My current plan to work around this is to look at the header for the link and examine it to see if it contains X-Frame-Options. If so, I will set it to forego the iframe and just open up the original site in a new tab.

This method seems to work for some websites (like pitchfork.com) because when I request the header from pitchfork.com, I get the following:

```
server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
date: Wed, 27 Jan 2016 17:47:54 GMT
x-varnish: 912263733 912263044
age: 8
via: 1.1 varnish
connection: keep-alive
```

**Problem:**

For some websites (like vox.com), when I load them in an iframe, [the chrome developer console tells me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCRFH.png) that x-frame-options is preventing the site from loading in an iframe. But when I examine the header, x-frame-options is nowhere to be found! All I get is this:

```
server: nginx/1.6.2
date: Wed, 27 Jan 2016 17:26:15 GMT
content-type: text/html
content-length: 172
connection: close
```

How is vox.com doing this? For further clarification, I tried using [this tool](http://www.tinywebgallery.com/blog/advanced-iframe/free-iframe-checker) that I found in another stackoverflow post and it also failed to correctly detect that vox.com was blocking iframes via x-frame-options.

1) Is Vox able to set the x-frame-options somewhere other than the header? If the latter, how can I detect and find that?

2) Any other alternate strategies you recommend for detecting iframe-unfriendly sites so that I can have them set to open in a new tab instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the network traffic recorded in the Chrome console.  In your app, you're looking at the headers of the HTTP `301 Moved Permanently` response, which then redirects you to the location that does return the `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` header.

Other methods, such as the newer [Content-Security-Policy header](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet#Defending_with_Content_Security_Policy_frame-ancestors_directive) or JavaScript code, may be used by other websites to prevent iframe embedding.  But in the case of vox.com, you're simply looking at the headers of the wrong response.

Comment: Great, looking in the network traffic part of the Chrome console revealed the header with the X-Frame-Options. 
I guess my problem now is that rails is not able to detect this when requesting the header for the website - not sure what redirecting is going on because this happens even when I request the header for the homepage: www.vox.com
Since this is more of a rails issue now, I will make a new question. Thank you!